# Proof check: Prove $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} x^2 + 3 = 4$.

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Prove $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} x^2 + 3 = 4$, i.e., $0<|x-1| < \delta \rightarrow |x-1||x+1| < \epsilon$.

Since we require $0<|x-1|$, $x$ is never $0$ and therefore there always exists an $M$ with $|x+1| < M|x-1|$.

Suppose $\delta = \frac{\sqrt{\epsilon} -1}{M}$.

Then, if $|x-1| < \delta$, we have $|x+1| < M|x-1| < \sqrt{\epsilon} - 1 < \sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Therefore, $|x+1||x-1| < \sqrt{\epsilon}\sqrt{\epsilon} = \epsilon$.

It's the first time I use this sort of $M$ in a limit proof, so I'm not sure I'm allowed (maybe it sometimes doesn't exist?), and furthermore I usually see people do this one using something analogous to $\delta = \min\{{\frac{\epsilon}{3},1}\}$. Could anyone confirm whether it works and is complete? Thank you very much!

Comment: Am I mistaken, but I get $\delta = -1 + 2\sqrt{1+\varepsilon}$?

Comment: $|x-1|>0 \implies x \in R$  i.e., $x$ can be zero and as such $M$ doesn't exist for $ x=0$.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha ahhh, you're right! We have to assume $|x-1| < 1$. Thank you very much! I think this counterexample could constitute a proper answer

Comment: @VeryConfused I'll attempt your solution as soon as I have time

Comment: @shintuku yes, now you get it. After that assumption you'll get $|x+1| |x-1|<3 |x-1|$ and then you need to show $3|x-1|<\epsilon$ which will occur only when $|x-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Therefore you need $|x-1|$ to be less than 1 as well as $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ i.e. it should be less than $min{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}}$

Comment: @AmanKushwaha thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks good to me just needs some clean up and clarification.
$0 < |x-1|$ so $|x-1|$ is never zero and therefore there always exists an $M$, $M > 0$, such that $|x+1| < M |x-1|$ by the Archimedean property I think.

Lastly, be sure to show why $|x-1| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$ in $$|x+1||x-1|<\sqrt{\epsilon}\sqrt{\epsilon}$$

Comment: Someone gave me a tip: notice that it is not certain such an $M$ exists given $\frac{|x+1|}{|x-1|}$ diverges

Comment: this becomes more evident when you notice the quantification of the definition: $\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta, \forall x$, in other words, for a given $\epsilon$ there exists a single $\delta$ for all $x$, such that $|x-1| < \delta \rightarrow $ etc., so you can't have $M$ changing in order to keep maintaining $|x+1| < M|x-1|$ true

Comment: I see now thank you @shintuku

Comment: @shintuku yes that's correct. That was the conceptual error in your proof. $\delta$ and hence, $M$ should depend on $\epsilon$ only. Thank you